# How can I maniulate my code to have the same output as shown in the docstring?

Tags: python

```
def make_str_from_column(board, column_index):
    """ (list of list of str, int) -> str

    Return the characters from the column of the board with index column_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_column([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 1)
    'NS'
    >>> make_str_from_column([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 2)
    'TO'
    >>> make_str_from_column([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 3)
    'TB'
    >>> make_str_from_column([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
    'AX'
    """
    e = ' '
    for e in board:
        i = ' '
        for i in e:
            return "".join(i[column_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute your return value with a comprehension:

```
return "".join(i[column_index] for i in board)
```